# Prevent USB hard drive enclosure from powering off after inactivity

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, power-management, external-hdd

I have successfully used 'hdparm' to disable APM (Advanced Power Management) on external USB hard drives.

Now I've come across a USB hard drive [enclosure](http://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-617) that itself turns the installed hard drive off after 10 minutes of inactivity. Disabling APM on the drive doesn't help because it's the enclosure doing the deed.

The enclosure is a [Transcend StoreJet 25S3](http://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-617), with USB 3.0 and UASP support, and 10 minute auto power save feature. The SATA-USB bridge controller used is an [ASmedia ASM1153E](http://www.asmedia.com.tw/eng/e_show_products.php?cate_index=97&item=133).

Is there any setting or command in Linux (Ubuntu/Mint) that can disable this annoying enclosure behavior?

Comment: brand? model? details?  links change, links die, links suffer from bitrot.

Comment: @cas True, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the auto-poweroff function is built into the enclosure, the simplest (and perhaps only) way of preventing it from kicking in is by creating a [Cron Job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) that periodically touches a file on the drive.

Start by giving the drive (partition) a [label name](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive), if it doesn't already have one. This allows Ubuntu/Mint to automatically mount it to the `/media/<username>` directory.

Then, in Terminal, edit your crontab by entering this command:

```
crontab -e
```

And add this line:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/touch /media/<username>/<labelname>/.stayawake &> /dev/null
```

The Cron Job will [touch](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/touch.1.html) a hidden file named `.stayawake` on the drive every 5 minutes, and redirect any resulting output (including errors) to `null` which is what you want considering the drive might not always be connected.

Note: The above Cron Job will only work while the user under which it was created is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do so "properly" is through a firmware update. MP Tool is able to set the firmware configuration including HDD spindown timer.
You should ask transced support for that or go to usbdev.ru and do it yourself, but there is a risk involved.